# Maintaining Collapse state after calling servlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets, bootstrap-4

I have jsp page where i have panel group with collapsible list. When i call servlet function, it will render to the same page with data. But the collapsible menu gets refreshed. How to maintain the previous state?

```
        <div class="panel-group">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h5 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2"><li  class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">A</li></a>
                </h5>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <a href="Servlet?environment=<%=env%>&date=<%=date%>&test=AB" id = "A" ><li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">B</li></a>
                    <a href="Servlet?environment=<%=env%>&date=<%=date%>&test=AB" id = "B"><li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">C</li></a>
                    <a href="TestServlet?environment=<%=env%>&date=<%=date%>&test=AB" id="security"><li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">D</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Used [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store current state .

Comment: Hello @Swati.. Could you give me an example on how to do it....that would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value in localStorage whenever you click on any `<a>` and then store the value of `href` in `localStorage` and then always call the function `onload` of your page to open only those panel which was clicked by user.

So, here is javascript code :

```
//onload of your page this will get called
function check_storage() {
//check if there is any value in localStorage
  if (localStorage.getItem("save") != null) {
  //get that value
    var value= localStorage.getItem("save");
    console.log(value);
    show(value); //call function
  }
}
//onclick of <a> this will get called
function save(el) {
//store the href to some variable
  var save = el.getAttribute("href");
   console.log(save);
  localStorage.clear();//clear previous data
  localStorage.setItem("save", save);//add data to storage

}

function show(date_value) {
  console.log("in")
  $(date_value).toggle();//to show panel 

}
```

Your html will look like below :

```
 //add onload event
 <body onload="check_storage()">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="panel-title">    //add onclick
          <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="save(this)" href="#collapse2">
            <li class="list-group-item" style="background-color: #394263;color: white">A</li>
          </a>
        </h5>
      </div>
     ...
  </div>
</body>
```